# MySQL,SQL How get all rows?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT
  pm.PaymentOperationID as PaymentOperationID,
  pm.DateOperation as DateOperation,
  ac.Name as AccountName
FROM PaymentOperations as pm
LEFT JOIN Account as ac on ac.AccountID = pm.AccountID
WHERE pm.Status = 'false' ORDER by pm.DateOperation DESC
```

if we use this query we get 20 rows from table database, but now we would like get              `SUM(pm.Cost)`.

For this we are doing:

```
SELECT
      pm.PaymentOperationID as PaymentOperationID,
      pm.DateOperation as DateOperation,
      ac.Name as AccountName,
      SUM(pm.Cost) as Costs
    FROM PaymentOperations as pm
    LEFT JOIN Account as ac on ac.AccountID = pm.AccountID
    WHERE pm.Status = 'false' ORDER by pm.DateOperation DESC
```

AND now we get only one row.

Tell me please why we get only one row and how make that we get all 20 rows with input `Costs`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting 1 row because you are using an aggregate function `SUM()` with out grouping your records so your whole table is treated as one group and sum will be applied to all the costs of 20 rows ,if you need to get your results then you should use group by with appropriate grouping column,from your question it isn't clear to sum costs for which group ?

```
SELECT
      pm.PaymentOperationID as PaymentOperationID,
      pm.DateOperation as DateOperation,
      ac.Name as AccountName,
      SUM(pm.Cost) as Costs
    FROM PaymentOperations as pm
    LEFT JOIN Account as ac on ac.AccountID = pm.AccountID
    WHERE pm.Status = 'false' 
  GROUP BY some_column /* like GROUP BY PaymentOperationID for each PaymentOperationID you can see the total cost */
ORDER by pm.DateOperation DESC
```

[*MySQL Extensions to GROUP BY*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html)

[*GROUP BY (Aggregate) Functions*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum)